# Uncover lines of an align environment with beamer

Tags: beamer, align, overlays

Is there any way to uncover equation-lines of an align* environment line per line in a frame conveniently?

somethink like

```
\begin{align*}[<+->]
    a &= b \\
    b &= c \\
    \Rightarrow \quad 
    a &= c \\
\end{align*}
```

or at least only one annotation per line.

Comment: Section 23.4 of the beamer manual describes how this can be done

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Since you have an untagged environment, you can use

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
    \onslide<1->{a &= b \\}
    \onslide<2->{b &= c \\}
    \onslide<3>{\Rightarrow \quad 
    a &= c}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For a tagged environment additional work has to be done, as described in Section **23.4 Uncovering Tagged Formulas Piecewise** of the `beamer` manual:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
    \onslide<1->{a &= b \\}
    \onslide<2->{b &= c \\}
    \onslide<3>{\Rightarrow \quad 
    a &= c \\}
\notag
\end{align}
\vskip-1.5em
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, I didn't realize this worked, as I had made another mistake and misinterpreted the errors i got. I haden't found this when googling/searching here for solutions however.

Comment: What is an untagged environment?

Comment: @RodolfoOviedo `{align}` is tagged because it's numbering each of the lines.  `{align*}` is untagged because it doesn't number the lines.

Comment: This will also work if you use `<+->` instead of `<1->` etc, and then you don't have to renumber everything if you make an edit.

Comment: Thanks for the hint for tagged environments.