# Beamer: Uncovering lines in the align environment

Tags: beamer, align

I have been referencing this question [Uncover lines of an align environment with beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60689/uncover-lines-of-an-align-environment-with-beamer), but I am having additional trouble that none of the comments or answers seem to

```
\begin{frame}
Let $i\neq j$. Choose $\{e_1,...e_i,...,e_j,...,e_n\} \subset \mathbb{C}^n$
to be set of pair-wise orthogonal unit vectors (i.e., $\langle e_k,e_l 
\rangle = \delta_{kl}$).  \pause Replace $e_j$ with $ze_i$, where $|z| = 1$, 
so that $\{e_1,...,e_i,...,ze_i,...,e_n\}$.  \pause Note that $B = I + B_0$. 
Hence,

\begin{align*} \onslide<3->\tau_{n} (CB) =&~ 0 \\ \onslide<4->\tau_n(CI) + 
\tau(CB_0) =&~ 0 \\ \onslide<5->a_{ij} \overline{z} + \overline{a}_{ij} z 
=&~ 0 \\ \onslide<6->Re(a_{ij} \overline{z}) =&~ 0 \end{align*}

\pause If $z = 1$, then $Re(a_{ij}) = 0$.

\pause If $z = -i$, then $Re(a_{ij} i) = -Im(a_{ij}) = 0$. Therefore, 
$a_{ij} = 0$. 
%So that are collection becomes
\end{frame}
```

...hmmm...the code didn't enter in nicely. Well, hopefully you can see the problem that I am unsure how to deal with. In the align environment, I have multiple occurrences of `\onslide`, and just outside of it I have multiple occurrences of `\pause`. What this results in is sequence of things appearing out of order. How do I fix this? I tried changing the arguments of each `\onslide`, but that didn't help any.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Code can be displayed by indenting it with 4 spaces, or selecting it and pressing `{}` above the edit box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is the syntax of the `\onslide` commands.  You should be writing

```
\onslide<3->{....}
```

where `...` is the material to which this declaration applies, e.g.

```
\onslide<3->{\tau_{n} (CB) &= 0 \\}
```

instead of `\onslide<3->\tau_{n} (CB) &= 0 \\`.  That will fix up much of your problem with the display.  Then the `\pause` after the alignment should be given the next slide number, in this case `7`, by writing

```
\pause[7]
```

instead of just `\pause`.  With these changes each element on your slide will be revealed in order.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Let $i\neq j$. Choose
  $\{e_1,\dots,e_i,\dots,e_j,\dots,e_n\} \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ to be
  set of pair-wise orthogonal unit vectors (i.e.,
  $\langle e_k,e_l \rangle = \delta_{kl}$).
  \pause
  Replace $e_j$ with $ze_i$, where $|z| = 1$, so that
  $\{e_1,\dots,e_i,\dots,ze_i,\dots,e_n\}$.
  \pause
  Note that $B = I + B_0$.  Hence,

  \begin{align*}
    \onslide<3->{\tau_{n} (CB) &= 0 \\}
    \onslide<4->{\tau_n(CI) + \tau(CB_0) &= 0 \\}
    \onslide<5->{a_{ij} \overline{z} + \overline{a}_{ij} z &= 0 \\}
    \onslide<6->{Re(a_{ij} \overline{z}) &= 0}
  \end{align*}

  \pause[7]
  If $z = 1$, then $Re(a_{ij}) = 0$.

  \pause
  If $z = -i$, then $Re(a_{ij} i) = -Im(a_{ij}) = 0$.
  Therefore, $a_{ij} = 0$.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```