# Problem with using pause and onslide in one frame

Tags: beamer, align, pause

I'm trying to use `\pause` in align mode but it's not working. I ended up using `onslide` which it works fine. However, when I use both of them in one frame, some of `onslide` work while the other are not. This is a minimal example to regenerate the problem.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
AAAAA CCCCCC \\
\pause 
AAAAA CCCCCC
\begin{align*}
    \onslide<1->{a &= b \\}
    \onslide<2->{b &= c \\}
    \onslide<3>{ a &= c}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the first two lines show up together. While  the third line appears in the next slide. When I comment out `\pause`, the problem goes away. How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" is, that the first `pause` already creates an overlay, so you have to start counting at `2` in the `align` and not at `1`. But to make this more flexible, simply don't use hard coded numbers but relative overlays.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
AAAAA CCCCCC \\
\pause 
AAAAA CCCCCC
\begin{align*}
    \onslide<+->{a &= b \\}
    \onslide<+->{b &= c \\}
    \onslide<+>{ a &= c}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With the above approach, `onslide` has no impact on number of equations if the mode is `align`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion would be not using `align`. Otherwise http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323432/36296 might be of interest, the long explanation can be found at "23.4 Uncovering Tagged Formulas Piecewise" in the beamer user guide.

Comment: "23.4 Uncovering Tagged Formulas Piecewise"  solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The `\pause` command does exactly what it says: stops the frame where it is. As such, if you then specify slide 1 later on in the frame, that material will appear with slide 2, as you've observed. I strongly advise *not* mixing `\pause` with any more complex overlay control: `\pause` is simple but limited, other overlay specs are more complicated but as a result more powerful. [Sam Carter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332138) shows that if you want the align to appear after the text, it's easy with a mix of approaches. If you want the two to appear at the same time, I'd go with something like

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\onslide<+->{AAAAA CCCCCC} \\
\onslide<+->{AAAAA CCCCCC}
\begin{align*}
    \onslide<.(-1)->{a &= b \\}
    \onslide<.->{b &= c \\}
    \onslide<+->{ a &= c}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(See [Relative overlay specification in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer/) for more on relative overlay specifications.)

Comment: Why with `align`, number of equations show up before the equations?

Comment: @CroCo The `align` environment is set twice, and this makes life very tricky: this is mentioned in the `beamer` manual