# LaTeX: question on align, pause and beamer

Tags: beamer, align, pause

I want to know how to make the command "pause" work in beamer along with the align environment.  Pause works nicely in equation and eqnarray environments, however.  A sample code is given below.  I have the following restrictions:

- I need to show equations and components of it, slowly, as it is a highly mathematical course.  As I am comfortable with beamer, I would like to use it.
- I do NOT want to use the command "uncover", which although very powerful, becomes difficult to use, when there are many equations.  Pause is a lot easier and it will not require too many changes to the code that I already have.
- I already have about a thousand equations written using the align environment for a book.  At the time of writing the book, I did not know about this difficulty.  Had I known about it, I would have used align only when it was absolutely necessary.

The code is given below:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{amsmath,beamerthemesplit} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
 Some text. 
 \pause 
 \begin{eqnarray}
 a = b \pause \\ 
 c = d
 \end{eqnarray}
 \pause
 \begin{align}
 a = b \pause \\ 
 c = d
 \end{align}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: From the beamer user guide: After some experimentation he finds that \pause only does not work in align environments. He immediately writes an email about this to beamer’s author, but receives a polite answer stating that the implementation of align does wicked things and there is no fix for this. Also, Euclid is pointed to the last part of the user’s guide, where a workaround is described.

Comment: `\pause` is pretty crude anyway. I'm surprised you use it. If you are serious about (1), provide a Minimal Working Example. If you really only wanted to do (2), let us know as this is not a question in that case and, therefore, not suitable for this site. You might want to get a blog instead.

Comment: In any beamer environment, the following code may be tried and it would not work:     I have already explained in my original post that I do not want to use uncover, which is what is suggested at the end of the beamer guide.  I find uncover more cumbersome to use, compared to the pause command.  Had I known about this difficulty, I would have reduced the usage of align.  Because of this problem, I have also decided to re-do my video tutorials, removing the usage of align.

Comment: Here is the minimal working code:  \documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,beamerthemesplit}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text. \pause
\begin{eqnarray}
a = b \pause \\
c = d
\end{eqnarray}
\pause
\begin{align} 
a = b \pause \\
c = d
\end{align}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is simply off topic: the site is not designed for discussion but for questions and answers. The `amsmath` environments were designed long before `beamer` was around, and furthermore, they were designed for typesetting not presentation.  So this is hardly a flaw in `align`. The `beamer` manual is explicit in addressing the issue and a workaround is described. If you have a technical question about the workaround, then ask it. If you simply don't like it, then there is no question to be answered. I've voted to close as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Mathematics, has to be presented in chunks for students to understand.  Although "uncover" is very powerful, it is difficult to use in large scale presentation of mathematics, while "pause" is very simple to use.  In view of this, the align command should be used sparingly in large mathematical documents, if that material has to be presented ever.   I request the first time users of align to keep this in mind.  I used to be a great fan of align myself, using it also in places, where I could have used equation or eqnarray.  Sorry if this is not place to make this statement.

Comment: I have now edited my original post.  Finding an answer to this question will be very useful to me.  Hopefully, it will be useful to at least a few others.

Comment: So if you do not like `\uncover`, how about `\onslide`? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60692/36296

Comment: maybe the question gets easier to answer if you describe why you don't like `uncover`. Is it just that you do not want to specify the overlay numbers by hand? `beamer` has a few overlay commands like `.`, `+` etc. which can make this task easier.