# Uncover lines of an align environment with beamer and xelatex

Tags: beamer, xetex, align

I'd like to do a line-by-line uncover of the lines in an `align*` environment in beamer. [The solution posted here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60692/62325) works great when compiled with `pdflatex`.

However, I am using `xelatex` for custom fonts, and the linked solution apparently doesn't work with `xelatex`.

Example ( I realize the algebra is not correct in the following, but I don't feel like redoing the screen shots :) ):

> main.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
    \onslide<1->{a &= \frac{b}{c} \\}
    \onslide<2->{b &= c \times d \\}
    \onslide<3>{\therefore \quad a &= \frac{d}{c}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with `pdflatex main` works as expected, but `xelatex main` produces this funkiness where only the left side of the alignment character `&` of each line are shown in transparent:

#### Slide 1:

[image: slide 1]

#### Slide 2:

[image: slide 2]

#### Slide 3:

[image: slide 3]

**How can I uncover line-by-line in `align*` with transparency using `xelatex`?**

Comment: Very good question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea what the problem with xelatex is, but as a workaround you could wrap the left and right sides separately in `\onslide`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
    \onslide<1->{a &= \frac{b}{c} \\}
    \onslide<2->{b} &\onslide<2->{= c \times d} \\
    \onslide<3->{\therefore \quad a} &\onslide<3->{= \frac{d}{c}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]