# Automate uncovering of lines of an align in beamer

Tags: beamer, align, overlays

The answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60692/12212 explains how to uncover lines of a tagged align in Beamer by wrapping the lines in `onslide` commands. It would be nice to have that done automatically without having to manually enter the `onslide` commands for each line of each align. How can I achieve the same result as the following example but without having to manually enter the `onslide` commands each time?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align}
\onslide<1->{abc & = def\\}
\onslide<2->{ & = ghi\\}
\onslide<3->{ & = 0.\\}
\notag
\end{align}
\vskip-1.5em
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will give a solution with LaTeX3 Programming Layer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{+b}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \begin{align} }
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } {#1}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \tl_if_empty:nF { ##1 }
          {
            \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \onslide<+->{ ##1 \\ } }
          }
      }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \notag \end{align} \vskip-1.5em }
    \l_tmpa_tl
  } { }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{myalign}
abc & = def \\
    & = ghi \\
    & = jkl \\
    & = 0.  \\
\end{myalign}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very nice solution!  What's the `+b` argument specifier? I've not seen that one before.

Comment: `b`: collect the whole body; `+b`: collect the whole body which may contain `\par` in it.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand your solution but it does exactly what I want and I look forward to studying it. I suggest one minor edit, which is to remove the `\\ ` from `& = 0.  \\ ` in the example. In my example I included the `\\ ` there because it is necessary to get the functionality I wanted to show. But your solution thankfully does not require it (just like it does not require the user to put `\notag`), and by removing it, it is easy to change from `myalign` to `align` in the example with no other change. Not a problem if you think it's clearer to keep it included.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same technique as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661242/36296 , you could use the `tabularray` package to emulate how an `align` would look like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{+b}{
\begin{tblr}{
  column{1}={co=1},
  column{Z}={co=1},
  column{odd}={halign=r},
  column{even}={halign=l},  
  colsep = 0pt,
  cells={mode=dmath},
  cell{1-Z}{1}={cmd=\action<+->},
  cell{1-Z}{2-Z}={cmd=\action<.->},
  cell{1-Z}{Z}={appto={\hfill \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}}
}
#1
\end{tblr}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{myalign}
abc & = def\\
 & = ghi\\
 & = 0.\\
\end{myalign}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for "back-porting" your answer here. I like this approach! It also gives me a nice motivation to study tabularray and start relying on it more often.

Comment: @scottkosty Be careful: once fallen in love with tabularray, you won't be able to stop using it :)

Comment: You be careful: once fallen in love with tabularray, I won't stop asking questions about it :)

Comment: @scottkosty  ohh  :P