# How to display multiline equations line by line in LYX (beamer)

Tags: beamer, equations, align, lyx

I have slide with long equation (eqnarray environment, see screen) and I would like to display each line separately in my .pdf file. How can I do that in LYX?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I add screen. Instead of displaying one slide with this long equation, I would like to get 5 slides where each next slide contains one more line of equation

Comment: Off-topic: [Don't use eqnarray](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001). Use `align` instead.

Comment: @Markov a few questions: 1. Is it OK to use align instead of eqnarray? 2. Is it OK if the lines are numbered? If your answers are "yes" and "yes", I *might* be able to make a LyX module that does what you want. More questions: 3. Are you familiar with "modules" in LyX? 4. What is your version of LyX? 5. What is your version of TeX Live, or MiKTeX? (the solution that I would try would require a relatively new version). 6. If it takes me a couple of weeks before I am able to figure out the solution, would that still be useful to you or by then it's too late?

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Rather not, I prefer to add number only to selected lines 3) I use only module customisable Lists (enumitem) 4) the newest one 5) I have the newest version of MikTex 6) I'm using LyX regularly so this will be useful in future

Comment: @Markov OK I'll think more about a solution using non-numbered lines. The solution I have in mind is based on this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611375/automate-uncovering-of-lines-of-an-align-in-beamer I'm sure it can be adapted to unnumbered but I don't know much of this type of LaTeX.

Comment: I wrote a module to support it. You can find it here: https://github.com/Udi-Fogiel/overlay-align

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you know how to incorporate "straight LaTeX" code in a `lyx` document.

If this assumption is correct, the following example should be of interest to you. The screenshot below shows the third slide, i.e., the slide with 3 of the 5 rows uncovered. Observe that rows 4 and 5 are grayed out, i.e., not yet fully uncovered, since I set `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}  % for "preview of coming attractions" appearance

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{align*}
          P_0 &= C_0-S_0 + K e^{-rT} \\
\uncover<2-> {&= S_0\Phi(d_{+}) - K e^{-rT} \Phi(d_{-}) -S_0 + K e^{-rT} }\\
\uncover<3-> {&= S_0\bigl[\Phi(d_{+})-1\bigr] - K e^{-rT}\bigl[\Phi(d_{-})-1\bigr] }\\
\uncover<4-> {&= S_0\bigl[1-\Phi(-d_{+})-1\bigr] - K e^{-rT}\bigl[1-\Phi(-d_{-})-1\bigr] }\\
\uncover<5-> {&= K e^{-rT}\Phi(-d_{-}) - S_0\Phi(-d_{+}) }
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I use LyX to don't have to write standard LateX formulas :(

Comment: @Markov - I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.

Comment: The reason why I'm using LyX is that I can type ctrl+F to produce fraction instead of wrtiting \frac{}{}. So your solution is a little time consuming if I have a lot of long equations. I hope that it's possible to do it in LyX in easiest way

Comment: @Markov - Can't LaTeX code be incorporated in a lyx document?

Comment: Of course it can be but your solution will be a little time consuming, but thank you because it works so until someone give another answer I will use your solution.