# Automate *alert*-uncovering of lines of an align in beamer

Tags: beamer, align, expl3, overlays

I am using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611688/12212) to automate uncovering lines of an align. However, I would like to alert on uncovering.

I don't know expl3 and my attempts to hack the answer referenced above have failed: I've tried adapting that answer to wrap the `\onslide` in `\alert<+>{}` as follows:

```
\alert<+>{\onslide<+->{ ##1 \\ }}
```

But I get an error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

I've also tried putting the `\alert<+>{}` on the inside:

```
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \onslide<+->{ \alert<+>{ ##1 } } \\ }
```

But I get the same error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

A more robust solution than hardcoding `\alert` inside would be to be able to set the overlay policy at a higher level. I mention this in a comment in my example below. But if that's not possible, I would be happy with a hardcoded `\alert`.

Example showing current behavior. I would like the align behavior in the example to be similar to the itemize behavior.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\oldalign\align
\let\endoldalign\endalign

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611688/12212 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{+b}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \begin{oldalign} }
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } {#1}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \tl_if_empty:nF { ##1 }
          {
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \onslide<+->{ ##1 \\ } }
          }
      }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \notag \end{oldalign} \vskip-1.5em }
    \l_tmpa_tl
  } { }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newenvironment{overlayalign}
  {
    \renewenvironment{align}{%
        \begin{myalign}
    }{%
        \end{myalign}
    }
  }
  {
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<alert@+|+->]
% I generally prefer the alert, but it would be nice to be able to change to
% the following, and align adapts (i.e., would not alert), just like itemize:
%\begin{frame}[<+->]

I would like behavior similar to itemize:

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}

\begin{overlayalign}
\begin{align}
abc & = def \\
    & = ghi \\
    & = jkl \\
    & = 0.  \\
\end{align}
\end{overlayalign}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using L3 programing layer

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__myalign_linesin_seq
\seq_new:N \l__myalign_linesout_seq
\seq_new:N \l__myalign_onelinein_seq
\seq_new:N \l__myalign_onelineout_seq

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{+b}
{
    \exp_after:wN \cs_set_nopar:Npn \cs:w tagform@ \cs_end: ##1
    {
        \cs:w maketag@@@ \cs_end: 
        { 
            \action<.-|alert@.> { ( \ignorespaces ##1 \unskip \cs:w @@italiccorr \cs_end: ) } 
        }
    }
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__myalign_linesin_seq { \\ } { #1 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__myalign_linesin_seq
    {   
        \seq_clear:N \l__myalign_onelineout_seq
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__myalign_onelinein_seq { & } { ##1 }
        \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__myalign_onelinein_seq
        {
            \int_compare:nNnTF { ####1 } = { 1 }
            { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__myalign_onelineout_seq { \action<+-|alert@+> { ####2 } } }
            { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__myalign_onelineout_seq { \action<.-|alert@.> { ####2 } } }
        }
        \seq_put_right:Nx \l__myalign_linesout_seq { \seq_use:Nnnn \l__myalign_onelineout_seq { & } { & } { & } }
    }
    \begin{align}
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l__myalign_linesout_seq { \\ } { \\ } { \\ }
    \end{align}
} { }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[<alert@+|+->]
        
        I would like behavior similar to itemize:
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \item one
            \item two
            \item three
        \end{itemize}
        
        \begin{myalign}
            abc & = def  \\
            & = ghi  \\
            & = jkl  \\
            & = 0. 
        \end{myalign}
        
        \visible<+->{test}
        
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'm switching the answer to this since I find it faster and the alignment seems more accurate to me. I used the implementation in the tabularray answer for a while and it worked great, so others who come across this thread should experiment between the two to see which works best for them.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach using `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{+b}{
\begin{tblr}{
  column{1}={co=1},
  column{Z}={co=1},
  column{odd}={halign=r},
  column{even}={halign=l},  
  colsep = 0pt,
  cells={mode=dmath},
  cell{1-Z}{1}={cmd=\action<+-|alert@+>},
  cell{1-Z}{2-Z}={cmd=\action<.-|alert@.>},
  cell{1-Z}{Z}={appto={\hfill \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}}
}
#1
\end{tblr}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<alert@+|+->]

I would like behavior similar to itemize:

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}

\begin{myalign}
abc & = def  \\
    & = ghi  \\
    & = jkl  \\
    & = 0.   \\
\end{myalign}

\visible<+->{test}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 interesting! Is it possible to make it so the last `&` on each row can be omitted? e.g., so the following could be used `abc & = def \\\` ? The reason for this is that I want to renew the align environment.

Comment: @scottkosty Please see my edit

Comment: thanks! Another issue is that the code does not change the `beamerpauses` counter. For example, if I put the itemize after the tblr, the overlays do not work as intended. I tried to step the `beamerpauses` counter in your `cmd` argument but it does not work well because it is run twice (because two cells per row). Any idea?

Comment: @scottkosty see my edited answer

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: @scottkosty You're welcome!

Comment: @scottkosty I updated the code a bit so one no longer needs to know the number of columns in advance

Comment: Ah thank you! That is indeed a helpful generalization.

Comment: @scottkosty You're welcome! And thanks a lot for the bounty!