# Centering a tabularray of math columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularray

I have an environment that relies on tabularray and the environment is not centered as I would like. I paste an example below, but first I give some preliminary info: I use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661242/12212) answer to show one line of a set of relations at a time in Beamer, alerting along the way. It works great, except that the table as a whole is not horizontally centered and causes problems in some of my use cases. I compare "myalign" (a new environment based on tabularray) to "align" to show how the centring differs, and the consequences (e.g., line breaks).

I use the "handout" class option in the example just to focus on the alignment. In practice, I don't use it and instead use the overlays. I also reset the equation counter to 0 to make the comparison between align and myalign closer.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{+b}{
\begin{tblr}{
  column{1}={co=1},
  column{Z}={co=1},
  column{odd}={halign=r},
  column{even}={halign=l},
  colsep = 0pt,
  cells={mode=dmath},
  cell{1-Z}{1}={cmd=\action<+->},
  cell{1-Z}{2-Z}={cmd=\action<.->},
  cell{1-Z}{Z}={appto={\hfill \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}}
}
#1
\end{tblr}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{align}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\overline{x}\right)^{2} & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}^{2}-2x_{i}\overline{x}+\overline{x}^{2}\right)\\
 & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}2x_{i}\overline{x}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\overline{x}^{2}
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{myalign}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

\begin{myalign}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\overline{x}\right)^{2} & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}^{2}-2x_{i}\overline{x}+\overline{x}^{2}\right)\\
 & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}2x_{i}\overline{x}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\overline{x}^{2}
\end{myalign}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{align}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

\begin{align}
\pi(\omega) & =\pi(w_{L},w_{B})\\
 & =R(w_{L},w_{B})-C(w_{L})\\
 & =p_B\cdot\min(q_D(w_{B}),q_S(w_{L}))-p_S\cdot q_S(w_{L}).
\end{align}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{myalign}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

\begin{myalign}
\pi(\omega) & =\pi(w_{L},w_{B})\\
 & =R(w_{L},w_{B})-C(w_{L})\\
 & =p_B\cdot\min(q_D(w_{B}),q_S(w_{L}))-p_S\cdot q_S(w_{L}).
\end{myalign}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(novice hacks I attempted that you can skip reading): I cannot tell if the problem is the centering outside the tabularray, or an issue with the column specifications. I tried adding `\centering` in various places, which did not seem to change anything. I tried experimenting with various column keys, as specified in the [tabularray documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf). Removing the `column{1}={co=1}` has a noticeable effect, but then the tblrs seem so be too far to the left. I've tried setting halign to "c" (instead of the default "j" for justify), but that doesn't seem to fix things. Changing the values of `rightsep` also does not seem to improve on the issue.

Comment: `co=1` on both columns means they have the same width. But the left column has shorter contents, which is right adjusted, therefore it has a large white space on the left. Add `hlines,vlines` to the `tblr` and you can easily see this.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Thanks, that helps a lot to understand what's going on. My novice interpretation of the root problem: It would be nice to have the table take up a shorter width, and then it could be positioned externally (e.g., with `centering`). However, since I want those custom equation labels far to the right, that means I need to figure out the correct centering *within* the table, which is challenging.

Comment: If I use `column{1}={co=1}` and `column{Z}={co=3}` the spacing is better for these particular examples, but I need the code to adapt to a lot of different use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to measure the width of the tabular with just the equations, no formula numbering or horizontal fills, then add half of `\textwidth` minus half the tabular width measured before as a `leftsep` to the first column.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\newsavebox\myalignbox
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{+b}{
    \sbox\myalignbox{%  
        \begin{tblr}{
                column{odd}={halign=r},
                column{even}={halign=l},
                colsep = 0pt,
                cells={mode=dmath}
            }
            #1
    \end{tblr}}
    \begin{tblr}{
            column{Z}={co=1},
            column{odd}={halign=r},
            column{even}={halign=l},
            colsep = 0pt,
            cells={mode=dmath},
            cell{1-Z}{1}={cmd=\action<+->},
            cell{1-Z}{2-Z}={cmd=\action<.->},
            cell{1-Z}{Z}={appto={\hfill \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}},
            column{1}={leftsep={\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\wd\myalignbox}}
        }
        #1
    \end{tblr}
}{}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{align}
        \setcounter{equation}{0}
        
        \begin{align}
            \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\overline{x}\right)^{2} & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}^{2}-2x_{i}\overline{x}+\overline{x}^{2}\right)\\
            & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}2x_{i}\overline{x}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\overline{x}^{2}
        \end{align}
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{myalign}
        \setcounter{equation}{0}
        
        \begin{myalign}
            \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\overline{x}\right)^{2} & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}^{2}-2x_{i}\overline{x}+\overline{x}^{2}\right)\\
            & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}2x_{i}\overline{x}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\overline{x}^{2}
        \end{myalign}
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{align}
        \setcounter{equation}{0}
        
        \begin{align}
            \pi(\omega) & =\pi(w_{L},w_{B})\\
            & =R(w_{L},w_{B})-C(w_{L})\\
            & =p_B\cdot\min(q_D(w_{B}),q_S(w_{L}))-p_S\cdot q_S(w_{L}).
        \end{align}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{myalign}
        \setcounter{equation}{0}
        
        \begin{myalign}
            \pi(\omega) & =\pi(w_{L},w_{B})\\
            & =R(w_{L},w_{B})-C(w_{L})\\
            & =p_B\cdot\min(q_D(w_{B}),q_S(w_{L}))-p_S\cdot q_S(w_{L}).
        \end{myalign}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

### Edit:

To fix the problem with nesting myalign inside lists replace `\textwidth` with `\linewidth`.

It seems you need to put the `\refstepcounter` in `preto` instead of `appto`, and the reference will be correct only if the `\label` is inside a cell that has `\refstepcounter`.

The following layout will allow the use of `\label` at the first column

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{+b}{
    \sbox\myalignbox{%  
        \begin{tblr}{
                column{odd}={halign=r},
                column{even}={halign=l},
                colsep = 0pt,
                cells={mode=dmath}
            }
            #1
    \end{tblr}}
    \begin{tblr}{
            column{Z}={co=1},
            column{odd}={halign=r},
            column{even}={halign=l},
            colsep = 0pt,
            cells={mode=dmath},
            cell{1-Z}{1}={cmd=\action<+->},
            cell{1-Z}{2-Z}={cmd=\action<.->},
            cell{1-Z}{Z}={appto={\hfill (\theequation)}},
            column{1}={leftsep={\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-0.5\wd\myalignbox}},
            column{1}={preto={\refstepcounter{equation}}},
        }
        #1
    \end{tblr}
}{}
```

and if you want to be able to use `\label` in every cell add `cell{1-Z}{2-Z}={preto={\addtocounter{equation}{-1}\refstepcounter{equation}}},` to the tblr options,

Comment: This is great! Thank you! There are a few use cases that my simple examples didn't cover that are looking strange. I will dig into them, experiment, and post back here.

Comment: The main issues I have are if I use an equation label, the value of the reference is not correct (which I think is kind of expected); and if I nest the myalign (e.g., inside an itemize), then the indentation causes problems. If I can't figure these issues out though, I will ask another question with an example. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @scottkosty, see my edit

Comment: Works well! Thanks for those edits. I used the "use `\label` in every cell" option you gave since LyX chooses the label location. I add 2 notes, just in case anyone wants to use this solution: (1) I now use `cell{1-Z}{1}={cmd=\action<+-|alert@+>},` and `cell{1-Z}{2-Z}={cmd=\action<.-|alert@.>},` so that the lines are alerted when first uncovered; and (2) at the beginning of `\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}` I save the 'beamerpauses' counter and then after the first `tblr` I restore 'beamerpauses' from the saved value. This is because I use `\onslide<+->{}` in the math expressions sometimes.

Comment: @scottkosty, is there a way to implement "like align" environments dynamically in LyX? e.g., via math macro, local layout or a module file? I once tried and did not succeed without redefining the `align` environment itself.

Comment: Indeed I redefine the `align` environment. I'll send you an email with my current hackish approach. I did not think of trying to use/abuse LyX's math macro feature for this. Maybe there is a way, but I don't currently know how.